# Azure Active Directory B2C resource owner password credentials flow (server-to-server)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

we want to check user credentials in a server process against a Azure Active B2C instance.
This is working using the resource owner password credentials flow.
However, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom) states that this flow isn't supported:

> Server-to-server - The identity protection system needs a reliable IP
>   address gathered from the caller (the native client) as part of the
>   interaction. In a server-side API call, only the server’s IP address
>   is used. If too many sign-ins fail, the identity protection system may
>   look at a repeated IP address as an attacker.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to disable the identity protection system checks in
  this scenario?
- Is there another way to validate user credentials
  against Azure Active Directory B2C from a background process (without
  user interaction) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those is possible today. If you update your question with the scenario, perhaps there can be alternative ways to accomplish it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. We were basically trying to authenticate users against various authentication sources via a single interface and therefore needed to validate the credentials. But we then went a different road because of the above limitations and security implications.

Comment: what did you go with? I am trying to figure out how to sign-in users without them entering credentials manually, and thought to build a stub form in my web app to have credentials auto-filled in by a script and then use this flow.